# Private memory browser grows a lot faster than expected for JavaScript application

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory

I am creating a JavaScript application on top of a library ([dwv](https://github.com/ivmartel/dwv)). I noticed that even though the JavaScript heap has a size of 128MB, the private memory of the tab is ~1.2GB! This is true even when the chrome debugger is closed.

Is  there a way I can identify what is causing this extreme private memory use?

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550358/chrome-tab-memory-keeps-growing-heap-size-stays-the-same) related question it is suggested that chrome only takes the memory when it is available and uses it for optimization. In my case however, it crashes when it cannot allocate the ~1.2GB of memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering, it was that dwv uses for every image a separate canvas. Each of these has its own buffer taking up private memory.