# THREE.js horrible performance

Tags: three.js

Playing around a bit with THREE.js and I have just added two objects to a scene, one in the center and one spinning around it and the camera spinning around both objects.

This simple thing makes my Macbook pro 2015 go crazy. In a matter of seconds after loading the page the fan goes on max and everything in the computer becomes slow.

This happens both in safari and chrome. WebGL is on.

I know could try to lock the frame rate. But is this a general problem of Three.js or does it depend on poorly written code? If poorly written code could you give me pointers to what I should think about and what I have done wrongly with this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js webgl - geometries</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <script src="./three.js"></script>
        <style>
            html, body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
        <script type="module">

            var container;
            var camera, scene, renderer;
            var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
            var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
            var mercury;

            init();
            animate();

            function init() {
                container = document.getElementById( 'container' );
                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 20, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
                camera.position.z = 1800;
                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x333333 );
                var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
                light.position.set( 0, 0, 1 );
                scene.add( light );

                light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
                light.position.set( 1, 0, 0 );
                scene.add( light );

                light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
                light.position.set( -1, -1, -2 );
                scene.add( light );

                // shadow
                var canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
                canvas.width = 128;
                canvas.height = 128;

                var context = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
                var gradient = context.createRadialGradient( canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, 0, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, canvas.width / 2 );

                gradient.addColorStop( 0.1, 'rgba(210,210,210,1)' );
                gradient.addColorStop( 1, 'rgba(255,255,255,1)' );

                context.fillStyle = gradient;
                context.fillRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );

                var shadowTexture = new THREE.CanvasTexture( canvas );
                var shadowMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: shadowTexture } );

                var radius = 200;
                var geometry1 = new THREE.IcosahedronBufferGeometry( radius, 1 );
                var count = geometry1.attributes.position.count;
                geometry1.addAttribute( 'color', new THREE.BufferAttribute( new Float32Array( count * 3 ), 3 ) );

                var geometry2 = geometry1.clone();
                var geometry3 = geometry1.clone();

                var color = new THREE.Color();
                var positions1 = geometry1.attributes.position;
                var positions2 = geometry2.attributes.position;
                var positions3 = geometry3.attributes.position;

                var colors1 = geometry1.attributes.color;
                var colors2 = geometry2.attributes.color;
                var colors3 = geometry3.attributes.color;

                for ( var i = 0; i < count; i ++ ) {
                    color.setHSL( ( positions1.getY( i ) / radius + 1 ) / 2, 1.0, 0.5 );
                    colors1.setXYZ( i, color.r, color.g, color.b );
                    color.setHSL( 0, ( positions2.getY( i ) / radius + 1 ) / 2, 0.5 );
                    colors2.setXYZ( i, color.r, color.g, color.b );
                    color.setRGB( 1, 0.8 - ( positions3.getY( i ) / radius + 1 ) / 2, 0 );
                    colors3.setXYZ( i, color.r, color.g, color.b );
                }

                var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
                    color: 0xffffff,
                    flatShading: true,
                    vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
                    shininess: 0
                } );

                var wireframeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x000000, wireframe: true, transparent: true } );

                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry3, material );
                var wireframe = new THREE.Mesh( geometry3, wireframeMaterial );
                mesh.add( wireframe );
                scene.add( mesh );

                var mercuryGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(50,15,15);
                var mercuryMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial(); 
                mercury = new THREE.Mesh(mercuryGeo, mercuryMat); 
                scene.add(mercury); 

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
            }

            function onWindowResize() {
                windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
                windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            }

            function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                render();
            }

            var t = 0;
            function render() { 

                var timer = Date.now() * 0.0001;
                camera.position.x = Math.cos( timer ) * 2500;
                camera.position.z = Math.sin( timer ) * 2500;
                camera.lookAt( scene.position );

                t += 0.01;          
                mercury.rotation.y += 0.03;

                mercury.position.x = 1000*Math.cos(t) + 0;
                mercury.position.z = 1000*Math.sin(t) + 0; // These to strings make it work

                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code runs absolutely fine on my machine. Here is a live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Lmftsqzb/

Comment: Thats nice. My fan goes bananas straight away. The heap memory in chrome stays at about 6MB, but checking in the activity manager the memory used is close to 1GB. Sounds similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550358/chrome-tab-memory-keeps-growing-heap-size-stays-the-same My thought is that there is a memory leak somewhere. @Mugen87 chrome doesn't start to use a lot of memory for you?

Comment: No, everything is fine. Are you using the latest macOS version for your MacBook? Upgrading the OS also upgrades the graphics driver.

Comment: I am, v10.14.5 (Mojave). core i5, 8gb ram, Intel iris graphics 6100. I've test in, Chrome, Safari and Firefox. As soon as I run the animation above my computer get  way way slower. Memory usage of that tab goes up 1GB more or less in each browser, and CPU never goes above 60%.

Comment: Consider to report this issue to the Apple support. It really sounds like a device issue.